# How to remove double quotes from json object type JSON value with remove "\r\n \ " tried many times

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

Problem :
[{"MetaId":4,"FilePrefix":" as- apt05 - 04 - 2023", "RequestjView":"{ \r\n  "article": {\r\n    "article_doi": "10.1139/cgj-2022-44441",\r\n    "data": null\r\n  },\r\n  "RequestID": "SCP2304110002"\r\n}"}]

Expected :
[{"MetaId":4,"FilePrefix":" as- apt05 - 04 - 2023", "RequestjView":{ "article": {"article_doi": "10.1139/cgj-2022-44441","data": null},"RequestID": "SCP2304110002"} }]

Answer (score 1):

If we take this data in a variable then variable name is rawData and

```js
let rawData = '[{"MetaId":4,"FilePrefix":" as- apt05 - 04 - 2023", "RequestjView":"{ \r\n "article": {\r\n "article_doi": "10.1139/cgj-2022-44441",\r\n "data": null\r\n },\r\n "RequestID": "SCP2304110002"\r\n}"}]';

/* replace these from \r, \n, \, "{ and }" */
rawData = rawData.replace(/\\n/g, '').replace(/\\r/g, '').replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/\"{/g, '{').replace(/\}"/g, '}');

/* convert it in object */
var dataaF = JSON.parse(rawData);

/* help of alert you can see the converted data */
alert(dataaF[0].RequestjView);
```

Comment: You'd be better to use snippets in future and also to use `console.log` instead of `alert`

Comment: Assuming "\n" is text and not a newline, you can also use `.replaceAll('\\n', '')` or a combined regex such as `/[\\r\\n]/g`